# Horizontal bars with start and end positions using hvplot or holoviews

Tags: python, holoviews, hvplot, holoviz

Is there a simple way to plot horizontal bars that have different starting positions? The closest example I found in the reference galery is implemented as segments : http://holoviews.org/reference/elements/bokeh/Segments.html

Comment: Check out this question + answers for alternatives. You could also use hv.Curve instead of hv.Segments: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442995/how-to-visualize-time-span-with-holoviews